# WebMethod performance slows

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a very basic JavaScript AJAX request using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "TabbedSummaryPage.aspx/RunReport",
    data: "{'itemId': '', 'lType': '', 'reportId': '', 'requestXml': ''}",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    }
});
```

Which is calling and executing the following C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static RunReportResponse RunReport(string itemId, string lType, string reportId, string requestXml)
{
    var result = new RunReportResponse();
    return result;
}

public struct RunReportResponse 
{ 
    public string reportTitle;
    public string reportError; 
    public string reportHtml;
    public string reportStyles;
    public bool showWordMenu;
}

public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
}
```

I've stripped everything down so nothing is really being executed.

If I make multiple concurrent AJAX requests something strange starts to happen.

The average time to get the first byte from the response is around 50ms if I make 11 requests but 5 of them always take between 2 and 3 seconds to respond with the first byte.

When I added some logging to find out what was going on it seems it is always the last set of requests, whether I send 6 requests and get 3 slow requests back, or I send 11 requests and get 5 slow requests back, it is always the last requests to be executed by ASP.NET which IIS provides a response to the client with an added 1000+ milliseconds.

We have a high performance app which relies on responding to these requests without a delay so it is imperative we can figure out what is causing this delay.

The same test results are found in Internet Explorer 11, Chrome and Firefox.

Requests which don't use the WebMethod attribute don't suffer this issue.

The following is the headers sent during a request:

```
POST /pharmadotnet/Pharma/TabbedSummaryPage.aspx/RunReport HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpReques
Referer: http://localhost/pharmadotnet/Pharma/tabbedsummarypage.aspx?lType=coInfo&itemId=1293&compId=co&reportingCurrency=&sceName=&showTabs=
Content-Length: 223
Cookie: sTab=tabs-1; ASP.NET_SessionId=r01d2eqjxu0vdnexbl5mmd3p; curSessionId=r01d2eqjxu0vdnexbl5mmd3p; NewSession=true; __AntiXsrfToken=ec03abb28ee14f50a18e34216aa59d85; .ASPXUSERDEMO=DF6CD4223C47DB289B82E0240DAB40AAF253BACE9A753863E77BA07F9CEE61D00235255A2BAA58F555ECF3166D8470E77654DB8C3E2594E54B5BAF38A5ACDCCA5FDED79ECD0B89DC3583B4F7E56911C15EE894365CA1444CF0A8D2AB8FEF19AA915CE3989F07DCFE6F4941DA69FBB38593BC51A9
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The following is the response headers from one of the requests:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 08 Sep 2015 12:50:58 GMT
Content-Length: 174
```

The same issue is exhibited regardless of whether we are debugging or not.

IIS is not configured to cache the request.
The WebForms page is not configured to cache the request.

Is there any particular reason as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Your WS just return an instance of RunReportResponse?

Comment: Yes, the response is `{"d":{"__type":"PharmaDotNet.WebReport.TabbedSummaryPage+RunReportResponse","reportTitle":null,"reportError":null,"reportHtml":null,"reportStyles":null,"showWordMenu":false}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was session locking.

By creating a separate WebForm, setting `EnableSessionState` to `false`, and moving the web method to the web form that doesn't make use of sessions I was able to work around the issue.

Comment: You will notice that "WebMethod" Attribute also has an "EnableSession=False" option you can put directly in the WebMethod to prevent this locking.
VB `<WebMethod(BufferResponse:=False, EnableSession:=False)>`

Comment: Thanks Darren, I will update my code to reflect this.

Comment: Should the web methods be moved to an ASMX instead?

Comment: @JacobMorrison that is what we ended up doing.